# install dblib on linux server trying to conenct symfony2 with sql server

Tags: php, sql, linux, symfony, pdo

I am on linux server but php is not installed in default directory it's in the opt.

when I runs command php -i it shows me that i have pdo = sqlite and dblib enabled;

but when i does phpinfo() it doesn't shows me those pdo_dblib driver.

I have to conenct symfony2 with sql server through doctrine. Even in symfony when I run

```
$ php app/console doctrine:query:sql "SELECT * FROM patientInfo"
```

gives me the correct result but through code gives me error "Could not find driver".

Whe I tryout a script out of symfony I gets the same error "Could not find driver".

Any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty clear that your webserver (apache?) isn't running same PHP version of your CLI (**C** ommand, **L** ine, **I** nterface)

`httpd -V` command will show you some informations about

Take a look to [that answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/428800/how-do-i-tell-apache-which-php-to-use) if you need more information about "switching" apache's php version.